# How to decode an empty object {} in elm?

Tags: json, elm

I am writing a JSON decoder for elm (0.19.1). My incoming json `Value` is an **empty object `{}`**. How can I decode that value to a type (here `NoPayload`)?

I tried to decode it with the help of `JD.string` decoder:

```
JD.string
    |> JD.andThen
        (\str ->
            if str == "{}" then
                JD.succeed NoPayload

            else
                JD.fail "Failed to decode non-empty payload to NoPayload decoder"
        )
```

But that resulted in an error:

```
Problem with the given value:

    {}

    Expecting a STRING
```

Alternatively, I am experimenting with `JD.null` and `JD.dict`, but I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can validate an empty object by using [`dict`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#dict) to convert the JSON object to a dictionary, then validate that there are no keys in the dictionary:

```
import Dict
import Json.Decode as JD exposing (Decoder)

emptyJsonDecoder : Decoder Payload
emptyJsonDecoder =
    JD.dict JD.int
        |> JD.andThen
            (\entries ->
                case Dict.size entries of
                    0 ->
                        JD.succeed NoPayload

                    _ ->
                        JD.fail "Expected empty JSON object"
            )
```

For validation:

```
JD.decodeString emptyJsonDecoder "{}"          == Ok NoPayload
JD.decodeString emptyJsonDecoder "{\"a\":123}" == Err "Expected empty JSON object"
```